# Pyspark: convert/cast to numeric type

Tags: pyspark

I have this method and I would need to cast the parameters from string to numeric to be able to operate:

`df = (df.withColumn('distance', dist_fast('LOCLAT', 'LOCLONG', 'LOCLAT2', 'LOCLONG2')))`

I would appreciate some help

Thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use method chaining correctly as below , this should convert to Integer type

```
df = df.withColumn('LOCLAT', F.col("LOCLAT).cast(T.IntegerType()).withColumn('LOCLONG', F.col("LOCLONG).cast(T.IntegerType()).withColumn('LOCLAT2', F.col("LOCLAT2).cast(T.IntegerType()).withColumn('LOCLONG2', F.col("LOCLONG2).cast(T.IntegerType())
```

Answer (score 0):

I have it:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
LOCATIONS_DW_df = LOCATIONS_DW_df.withColumn("LOCLAT", 
LOCATIONS_DW_df["LOCLAT"].cast(IntegerType()))
LOCATIONS_DW_df = LOCATIONS_DW_df.withColumn("LOCLONG", LOCATIONS_DW_df["LOCLONG"].cast(IntegerType())) ....
```